# Derivatives and connected sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

I'd like to prove the following two propositions:

a) Derivatives maps connected sets into connected sets

b) There exist functions which maps connected sets into connected sets that are not the derivative of any function.

thank you!

Comment: Hint: Derivatives satisfy the intermediate value property, a property also called the Darboux property.

Comment: For proposition b), finding an example is tough but [it can be done](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/88875/antiderivative-of-a-darboux-function)

Answer (score 2):

It's a theorem of Baire that the set of continuities of a derivative is dense. In particular, it's not empty. You can find a proof in Munkres's Topology (theorem 48.5). On the other hand, there are functions that satisfy the intermediate value property, and yet they are discontinuous everywhere. See the [Conway base 13 function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_base_13_function) for an example.